# Need example of using builder and factory design pattern together

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am studying design patterns and I know sometimes we can combine design patterns.
Now Builder design pattern and factory design pattern are almost same in purpose.
Sp is there any example, where we will use both patterns together?

Comment: Builder is kinda of extension of Factory (Factory is basically a builder without `buildPart()` methods).

Comment: factories build objects in a pre-configured way, a builder allows you to specify elements of how an object should be built before its built.

Answer (score 0):

There are subtle differences between [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) and [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

One example where you find Builder pattern used in conjunction with Factory is **Spring Application Context**, where you can have different declarations for the same class and construct it in different ways by calling different setter methods in each declaration.